# Dynamic component subject unsubscribes automatically

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a piece of code where I'm dynamically generating components using a "generateUnit" directive:

```
<ng-container 
    [generateUnit]="unit">
</ng-container>
```

The component being loaded by the directive subscribes to the input data, which is a BehaviorSubject, during ngOnInit():

```
@Input( ) data: 
BehaviorSubject<string>;

ngOnInit( ) {
   this.data.subscribe(....)
}
```

The same component also has a function which can update the data as follows :

```
updateData(value: string) {
    this.data.next("xyz");
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the same thing works perfectly if I use the same component as a child of the parent class rather than loading it dynamically through a directive. When I use the directive to load the component, the subscription works only when the component is rendered intitally and not afterwards. After that the subject loses its observer once ngOnInit( ) finishes and any following data.next( ) calls do not work since there are no observers now.

Why is the subject losing observers after ngOnInit( ) when I render the component through a directive and not otherwise ?

Comment: Could you please share also the : generateUnit directive? How are you passing that "data" to the component input?

Comment: Please show an example of the code that exhibits the issue. It would also make it easy for others to help if you reproduce the issue in StackBlitz.

Comment: export class UnitGenerator implements DoCheck { 
     declare componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;       declare differ: KeyValueDiffer<any, any>;    
  
constructor (private viewContainer Ref: ViewContainerRef, private differences: KeyValueDiffers){

 this.differ= this.differences.find({}).create();

 } 

@Input() set generateUnit (unit: any) { this.viewContainerRef.clear();
this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent<any>(unit. componentType); this.componentRef.instance.data = unit 

}

Comment: I'm sorry I can't send you the whole working code since it is something I need for my work assignment XD